# Get geometry and material of 3D Model - Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, mesh

I am attempting to make one 3D model orbit another, but as soon as I change my mesh from a wireframe box to a 3D Model's geometry it disappears.

```js
//this is inside a GLTFLoader.load (glftLoader.load('<model path>', (gltfScene) => {)

var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
            
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {
  color: 0xffffff, 
  wireframe: true
});

let pivot = new THREE.Object3D()
pivot.rotation.z = 0;
gltfScene.scene.add(pivot);

//let mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material); WORKING LINE
let mesh = new THREE.Mesh(gltfScene.scene.geometry, gltfScene.scene.material);
mesh.position.y = 2;
pivot.add(mesh);
```

What am I doing wrong? I get no errors, I have a feeling it may be to do with the scale of the 3D model but I'm unsure. Am I getting the geometry and material properties correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> let mesh = new THREE.Mesh(gltfScene.scene.geometry, gltfScene.scene.material);

I suppose this line breaks your code since `gltfScene.scene` (the result of `GLTFLoader`'s `onLoad()` callback) is an instance of `THREE.Group` which has no material or geometry property.

A glTF asset can hold more than one mesh so if you really want to extract the geometries and materials from it, you have to traverse through `gltfScene.scene` and process all meshes.

Comment: Check out how the traverse is done here: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/gltf-scene-traverse-get-typeerror-cannot-read-property-traverse-of-undefined/6151